# Want to print random strings without repeating one single time

Tags: python, random

Ok so i want to print random strings but i also want to not be duplicated a single time. i have this code:

```
import random
howmanytimes=int(input("howmanytimes?:"))

people=int(input("how many people do you want to comment ?:"))

f1=open("comentarios.txt","r")
mentions=random.sample(f1.readlines(),people)
for i in range(howmanytimes):
    print(mentions)
```

In the document i have a list of names one after the other, however the final result is this:

```
howmanytimes?:3
how many people do you want to comment ?:2
['@brother\n', '@hehe\n']
['@brother\n', '@hehe\n']
['@brother\n', '@hehe\n']
```

so in this case it prints random but repeats in the following 3 lines, someone can help to give random names in each line ?

Comment: You are printing same variable every time in loop. How do you expect it to be different?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick to first create a sample of required length and then slice through the sample:

```
mentions = random.sample(f1.readlines(), people*howmanytimes)

for i in range(0, len(mentions), people):
    print(mentions[i: i+people])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `random.sample()` to the for loop.

**test.txt content:**

```
this
is
my
test
file
for
so
```

**Code:**

```
import random

howmanytimes = int(input("How many times?:"))
people = int(input("How many people do you want to comment?:"))

samples = open("test.txt", "r").readlines()
for i in range(howmanytimes):
    mentions = random.sample(samples, people)
    print(mentions)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
How many times?:3
How many people do you want to comment?:2
['this\n', 'is\n']
['this\n', 'file\n']
['test\n', 'so']
```

**Note:**

You can remove the trailing newlines (`\n`) from lines with the following line:

```
samples = list(map(str.strip, open("test.txt", "r").readlines()))
```

In this case the output is:

```
>>> python3 test.py 
How many times?:3
How many people do you want to comment?:2
['test', 'my']
['so', 'test']
['this', 'test']
```

Comment: In the output, `'this'` is repeated twice. I suppose this is what OP is trying to avoid.